# Chronological lab data in R

Tags: r

This is my previous question:

[Long to wider format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65675527/long-to-wider-format/65675763#65675763)

I tried this code for the entire dataset:

```
new1 <- b_creatinine %>% 
  mutate(across(-ACCT,~as.character(.))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-ACCT) %>%
  group_by(ACCT,name) %>%
  mutate(name=paste0(name,row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('RESULT'),~as.numeric(.)))
```

There are two things happening here when I apply this to all my ID's:

I want my columns to be like this for each unique ID:

```
ACCT TEST_DATE1 RESULT1 TEST_DATE2 RESULT2 TEST_DATE3 RESULT3
  <int> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1 37733 3/2/2016         3 12/18/2016      2 11/1/2016        1
2 37734 5/30/2016        5 11/18/2016      4 12/2/2016        3
```

I am trying to get the `TEST_DATE1` (first test), `TEST_DATE2` (second test), and so on for each ID. Thus, each patient will have a different `TEST_DATE1` and result.

```
ACCT TEST_DATE1 RESULT1 TEST_DATE2 RESULT2 TEST_DATE3 RESULT3
  <int> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1 37733 9/1/2016         3 10/18/2016       NA 11/1/2016        NA
2 37734 9/1/2016         NA 10/18/2016       4 11/1/2016        3
```

But this what I'm getting when I apply the code to all my ID's:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amZ8S.png)

I want the test_date number to be each Id's unique first, second, third, and so on test date.

Two, some of my dates have multiple results on the same day and I need to take the average of all the results on the same day, would you know how I could do that? I also need to limit my results to 2 decimal points.

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Don’t add data/code as images. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You should have included a minimal reproducible example for this, to include all such possibilities.  Nevertheless, take this data-

## Sample data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ACCT = c(37733L, 37733L, 37733L, 37733L, 37734L, 
37734L, 37733L), TEST_DATE = structure(c(16809, 17023, 16811, 
16807, 17033, 16821, 16809), class = "Date"), RESULT = c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

df
> df
   ACCT  TEST_DATE RESULT
1 37733 2016-01-09      3
2 37733 2016-08-10      2
3 37733 2016-01-11      1
4 37733 2016-01-07      5
5 37734 2016-08-20      4
6 37734 2016-01-21      3
7 37733 2016-01-09      6
```

Now follow this code to solve your both problems

## Code

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(ACCT, TEST_DATE) %>% summarise(RESULT = mean(RESULT)) %>%
  group_by(ACCT) %>% mutate(testno = row_number(), resultno = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ACCT, names_from = c("testno", "resultno"), values_from = c(TEST_DATE, RESULT))

# A tibble: 2 x 9
# Groups:   ACCT [2]
   ACCT TEST_DATE_1_1 TEST_DATE_2_2 TEST_DATE_3_3 TEST_DATE_4_4 RESULT_1_1 RESULT_2_2 RESULT_3_3 RESULT_4_4
  <int> <date>        <date>        <date>        <date>             <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 37733 2016-01-07    2016-01-09    2016-01-11    2016-08-10             5        4.5          1          2
2 37734 2016-01-21    2016-08-20    NA            NA                     3        4           NA         NA
```

**Note: There are two suffixes at the end of each column_name ensuring that each test_result correspond with its result only.**